# gnuplot - place ylabel on top of plot after rotating it by 90 degrees

Tags: plot, layout, label, gnuplot

Rotating a ylabel is (or rather should be) pretty simple:

```
ylabel "whatever" rotate by 90
```

After I've rotated the ylabel, though, how can I place it on top of the plot, rather than at its side?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by putting it on top?  It sounds to me like you are trying to use the ylabel as a title, and there is another option for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to add the `offset` flag, e.g. `set ylabel "whatever" offset graph 0.5,0.5 rotate by 90`

Note: the `ylabel` is already vertical (rotated by 90˚), so your `rotate by 90` flag doesn't do anyting.

If you want an horizontal label on the top, you can also use the `set title "whatever"`. Just remember to remove the ylabel you just placed `unset ylabel`

Or you can create you own custom label to place whatever you want:

```
set label 1 "my label" at screen 0.5,0.4 rotate by 30
```

Please remember to use the right coordinate system read `help coordinates`

Moreover, as @Matthew tells in the comment below, it you take the `label` "road", you will probably need to adjust margins to get some extra space on the top (using `set title "whatever"` will handle this automatically). Have a read on `help margin` to catch up on this.

Comment: When using these commands it is likely necessary to manually adjust margins.  The `set _label` commands and `set title` will adjust the margins adequately, but the using `set label` will not adjust the margins automatically if the label falls outside the bounds.  For example, `set label "Testing" at graph 0,1` will place a label directly above the plot on the left hand side, but it will only display if extra top margin is added.